# Uninstall legacy versions of Office when deploying Office 365 Pro Plus

Tags: microsoft-office-365, deployment, microsoft-office-2013

In volume licensed editions of Office (ones with an MSI deployment), you can use [OCT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097(v=office.15).aspx) to create a package that will remove previous versions of Office when the new version is deployed.

Office 365 Pro Plus is Click-to-Run only, which means that OCT will not work with it. [ODT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36778) allows for some customization of Office 365 Pro Plus, but appears to lack the ability to remove previous versions of Office.

Is there a way to do this native to the Office 365 Pro Plus deployment, or does this really involve creating a script to check for every possible version of Office along with uninstall logic?

Comment: Using http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501 as a billy club might help…

Comment: @MikeyB but plenty of customers have Office 2010, 2007 or (ugh) 2003 around, still. :(

Comment: Can you create a package that runs the uninstallation and create a prerequisite package on which the Office365 package depends?

Comment: IMO, someone is always going to have a rogue copy of SharePoint Designer 2010 or some such running around.  

Has anyone tried specifying <Remove All="True"/> in the configuration.xml file for Click-to-Run setup to see if it cleans out old MSI versions?  TechNet isn't clear.

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried using [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)?  You could use wildcard operators, and tune them to catch whatever programs you'd like to remove.

For instance, try

```
wmic product where "name like '%Office%'"
```

You should catch most of what you're looking to remove.  You could tune it further to search specifically for the versions or components of Office you know the machines have installed, but it would be likely fine (after checking a couple cases) to have the 'Office' wildcard blast through; definitely doublecheck though!

So just script up something like this:

```
wmic product where "name like '%Microsoft Office%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

After you know you have your where clause tuned to catch just what you want.  To avoid any issues, you can make it as specific of a query as you want.

Comment: This might be a suitable workaround, but I'd like to know whether or not there's a native way to handle this in the Office 365 package itself. I'll wait a few days and if there's nothing better, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 8):

MDMarra,

When we were deploying O365 both the partners and MS said "you don't have to uninstall previous versions, they can stay on the computers".  To which I said "why leave them on there?" and they didn't have a great answer for me other than "you can uninstall them if you'd like".

So...that said...

The below wasn't around when I was deploying...it would've likely been overkill for my needs and we had multiple users that still needed Office 2010 around in conjunction with Office Pro Plus 2013 for a while...but I had bookmarked this last month for another potential client.

That said, here's what I had found.

In conjunction with the PowerShell App Deployment Kit found here:

http://psappdeploytoolkit.com/

Christian Fosund has a script on his site he's using for a very large deployment:

http://fosund.com/?p=494

> This is the script I have been using to deploy Microsoft Office 365
>   Pro Plus to nearly 5000 clients.  Its based on the awsome toolkit
>   PowerShell App Deployment Toolkit by Sean Lillis It will uninstall all
>   previous versions of Office and also remove additional applications
>   like Live Meeting, Communicator 2007, Conferensing Add-in etc  -- *Christian Foslund*

It's not a "download and run it" script.  You'll need the PADT and you'll need to change the script code for your particular environment needs, but it appeared to be worthy of a bookmark, and maybe it will help you as well.

Comment: Updated the link for the PowerShell App Deployment Kit, however the fosund.com link is returning a HTTP 500 error